# Magento 2.4.2 Elasticsearch Error: main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query

Tags: magento2, search, magento2.4, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2

**Elasticsearch** not working with main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query. I have tested the connection in the backend and it's showing successfull. But on the front-end in the catalog search, no result is showing. I have checked in **exception.log** and the following error is showing:

> main.CRITICAL:
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed
> to create query:
>  {   "bool" : {
> "must" : [
> {
> "terms" : {
> "visibility" : [
> "3",
> "4"
> ],
> "boost" : 1.0
> }
> }
> ],
> "should" : [
> {
> "match" : {
> "_search" : {
> "query" : "sams sams",
> "operator" : "OR",
> "prefix_length" : 0,
> "max_expansions" : 50,
> "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
> "lenient" : false,
> "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
> "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
> "boost" : 2.0
> }
> }
> },
> {
> "match" : {
> "name" : {
> "query" : "sams sams",
> "operator" : "OR",
> "prefix_length" : 0,
> "max_expansions" : 50,
> "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
> "lenient" : false,
> "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
> "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
> "boost" : 2.0
> }
> }
> }, .
> .........................
>    }\ }","index_uuid":"fMJ-vmT5Qu2_9PX3yJvMsw","index":"digi_live_product_1_v6","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For
> input string: \"sams sams\""}}}]},"status":400} at
>
> vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:632)"}
> []

I have tried every possible way like restart elastic search and reindex Magento but not working.
**Magento version**: 2.4.2
**Elasticsearch version**: 7.6

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of it, you have some numerical (int or decimal) attribute which is set to be searchable and causes the error as it would expect a number to be provided.

You can:

1. Check all your searchable attributes and make those which have a numerical data type to be set as not searchable.
2. If you want to keep the attribute as searchable, then enable [coerce](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html) on those fields in ES document mapping.

Comment: Thank you so much @Diana. The weight attribute is showing in the search. So I set to no in search and now everything works fine. You are the master in Magento.

Comment: you are most welcome, glad i could help! cheers!

Comment: @DianaBotean I have same issue with weight attribute i see that my weight attribute contain float value and when we enable for the search it cause the issue can you guide i want to make searchable of weight attribute.

Comment: have you tried changing the data type? make the attribute text/ varchar for example?

Comment: @DianaBotean the numerical attribute in sense do you mean eav_attribute table's backend type = int ?